# Postgres 9.4 JSON: Handle with double quotes inside value

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a json data with double quotes inside value.

```
For example, '{"resource": "xml version=\"1.0\" "}',
and when I run any json_function I get an error:

select '{"resource": "xml version=\"1.0\" "}'::jsonb - 'resource';

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Detail: Expected "," or "}", but found "1.0"
```

Can somebody explain me, please, how to handle these double quotes at this situation?

Comment: Please make sure that you didn't accidentally turn [`off` the `standard_conforming_strings` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS). I.e. run `select current_setting('standard_conforming_strings')`.

Comment: @pozs Thanks a lot, it works now!
The parameter was off by default.

Comment: it is advised to turn it `on` (which is its default since 9.1). the old syntax (i.e. where the backslash escapes) can be achieved with the `E'1st line\n2nd line'` syntax.